# Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) (in a simple matrix)

Tags: c

I'm new here and this is my first question regarding a small C program.
I've been learning this language recently and I don't know how to move yet. Could someone help me out?
Entering numbers in an array from time to time gives me this error:
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005).
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define R 5
#define C 5
int main(int argc,char argv[]){

    int A[R][C];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<R;i++){
        for(j=0;j<C;j++){
            printf("Numero [%d][%d]: ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",A[i][j]);
            printf("%d....%d",i,j);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<R;i++){
        for(j=0;j<C;j++){
            printf("%d",A[R][C]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should get compiler warnings. The line `scanf("%d",A[i][j]);` must be `scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);`. `scanf` needs the address of the variable where to store the integer value.  And your output should probably be `printf("%d ",A[i][j]);`.

Comment: in the end I realized these stupid mistakes by myself. Anyway, thank you for the answer.